# Data not changing after ajax call in Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have created an orders table that is taking the dates in datetime format and later on i am trying to get the data grouped by date so i have a total amount and numbers of orders made that particular day.

Now, I am trying to change the data in table according to the date picked in the date range picker using Ajax call. But there seems to be some problem that is not making me get the data after ajax call is made. Can someone help me out pointing where I am going wrong?

My views:

```
from .models import orders
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


def home(request):
    r_date = orders.objects.raw("SELECT id, SUM(amount) as amount, SUM(total) as total, (SUM(tax)*100/SUM(amount)) as rate, SUM(delivery_fee) as delivery_fee, SUM(tip) as tip, SUM(tax) as tax, SUM(sub_total) as sub_total, CONVERT(report_date, DATE) as report_date, COUNT(id) as count FROM orders Group By DATE(report_date) ORDER BY DATE(report_date) DESC;")
    r = round(r_date[1].rate, 2)
    t = [float(r), 0, 100]
    labels = ['net sales', 'deduction', 'tax']
    context = {"r_date": r_date, 't': t, 'labels': labels}
    return render(request, 'dashboards/demo.html', context)

@csrf_exempt
def datepickerview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.body)
        a = request.POST.get('fromDate')
        b = request.POST.get('toDate')
        # import code;
        # code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
        print(a, b)
        r_date = orders.objects.raw("SELECT id, SUM(amount) as amount, SUM(total) as total, (SUM(tax)*100/SUM(amount)) as rate, SUM(delivery_fee) as delivery_fee, SUM(tip) as tip, SUM(tax) as tax, SUM(sub_total) as sub_total, CONVERT(report_date, DATE) as report_date, COUNT(id) as count FROM orders WHERE DATE(report_date) BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-19' Group By DATE(report_date) ORDER BY DATE(report_date) DESC")
        context = {"r_date": r_date}
        return render(request, 'dashboards/demo.html', context)
```

My Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span id="someid"></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<div id="message"></div>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
             <!-- Illustrations -->

              <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Data</h6>
                  {{ amount }}
                </div>
                 <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">

                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Amount</th>
                      <th>Total</th>
                      <th>Orders</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                   {% for r in r_date %}
                    <tr>

                      <td>{{r.report_date}}</td>
                      <td>{{r.amount}}</td>
                      <td>{{r.total}}</td>
                      <td>{{r.count}}</td>
                    </tr>

                  {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});

$( document ).ready(function() {

     $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      fromDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      toDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      console.log(fromDate)

      function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');


    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'date' %}",
    data: {"fromDate": fromDate, "toDate": toDate},
    success: function () {
    $('#message').html("<h2>Data Posted</h2>")
      }
         });
});

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something mission in your question. I don't see you using the 'response' of your Ajax call. What I could 'guess' without seeing the error is
your Ajax success function does not have a param to receive the response.
so

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // use actual url
        url: 'url/to/post/request',
        data: {"fromDate": fromDate, "toDate": toDate},
        success: function (response) {
            // use Ajax response as needed
        }
    });
```